# Where do I physically input my Conditional Expression

Tags: zabbix

I am very new to Zabbix and am having to navigate it for some work. I want to change when I get notified about low disk space. I have done some research and found a potential expression:

`{hostname.vfs.fs.size[h;pfree].last(0)}<5`.

However, I have no configuration tab in the top left corner to implement this. I cannot seem to find a place to actually push this expression into.

I have Googled the problem but have not come across a missing configuration or solution in the results :(

I am sure I am navigating it incorrectly or am doing something silly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Zabbix is version 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have the top "Configuration" menu, it indicates that you do not have sufficient permissions to change the trigger expression.

If you installed this instance of Zabbix, log in as the default "Admin" user. If somebody else installed it, contact that person to obtain the needed permissions or make the configuration changes.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!